# Sending an SMS with your code infinite loading screen Account kit IOS

Tags: ios, account-kit

I'm using Account kit for Login using Phone number.

```
let accountKit = AKFAccountKit(responseType: AKFResponseType.accessToken)
var pendingLoginViewController: UIViewController?

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    pendingLoginViewController = accountKit.viewControllerForLoginResume()
}
@IBAction func loginWithEmail(sender: AnyObject) {
    let viewController = accountKit.viewControllerForPhoneLogin(with: nil, state: nil) as! AKFViewController
    viewController.enableSendToFacebook = true
    viewController.enableGetACall = true
    viewController.delegate = self
    present(viewController as! UIViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
private func generateState() -> String {
    let uuid = NSUUID().uuidString.lowercased()
    return uuid
}
```

Got SMS form Account kit but app infinite loading "`Sending an SMS with your code`" it should be go next screen for enter login code.

Thanks in Advance.
[image]

Comment: Check and Add your updated view code in main thread. If your are using in background then its freeze your UI.

Comment: Sorry not freeze, its showing infinite loading.

Comment: Ok, You can implement message sending delegate methods and get action successfully. After that you can stop loader. Or do other things.

Comment: Check here [https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/overview/] And Here [https://github.com/hansemannn/ti.accountkit]

Comment: @ShardaPrasad I have check all things its properly. I just try run after 30 minutes again then automatic work. may be some issue form Facebook side. Thanks for give your best time.