# Cant getting SMS code from facebook account kit

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, account-kit

I Implemented facebook account kit to verify mobile number and it is working properly in my phone but when i submit app to app store they saying "your app did not respond when we requested an OTP code."

"The steps to reproduce are:
Launch the app > create a new account > select the country (we selected US) > enter a phone number > the indicator spun indefinitely"

i dont know what is the issue. is there any account kit issue or something else.

did any one face this type of issue with apple?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I think that this guy had the same problem

[Sending an SMS with your code infinite loading screen Account kit IOS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50112814/sending-an-sms-with-your-code-infinite-loading-screen-account-kit-ios)

Facebook answer (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/accountkit/faq) to the question:  **I am experiencing delays in SMS delivery. What should I do?**

*In majority of the cases, SMS delivery will arrive within a few seconds. In some other cases, an SMS could be delayed due to routing issues or regional issues in the end users' locale.*

Maybe you should ask directly to facebook about possible issues.